# developing android mapping application with osmdroid

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

what are the features that osmdroid support, I have search the internet for information about it, but there is no much information about it, untill now I managed to use osmdroid to display the map online and offline, dispaly overlay and display the user location on the map, but what are the other features of osmdroid?????? 
and realy I found a lot of help from people here so thanks to them
and thanks to you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to find out what Osmdroid can do is to download the javadocs for the version you have and open up the index.html in your browser and explore the classes and methods.

It does most of what Google Maps can do, with the exception of satellite view. As you've already discovered, it can use offline maps and different sources for the tiles which Google can't do.

Comment: thanks NickT, but looking in the javadocs is the hard way are they any documantation of the features of osmdroid? does it support the search for Geopoint/POI for example?